# How recursively rename file extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have a lot of *.lub.lua files, and I want them to have only the .lua extension. I've used the `for /r %%x in (*.lub.lua) do if exist "%%x" ren "%%x" *.lua` but it doesn't take the .lub part away. What should I do?

Comment: I've removed the DOS tag. Please put it back and emphasis in your question if you're really using [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.lub.lua) do for %%b in ("%%~na") do echo(ren "%%a" "%%~nb.lua"
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R %%x in (*.lub.lua) do (
   set name=%%~Nx
   ECHO ren "%%x" "!name:.lub=.lua!"
)
```

This program just *display* the `ren` commands; if they are correct, remove the `ECHO` part in order to execute they.